# How to optimize orientdb match of large data with filter a relation twice?

Tags: orientdb

I am using orientdb recently. I load my db's data into orientdb, make the relation between different data type. Then try to find data by using orientdb's match command. But I found some match query is very slow. The reason cause this is I need filter a relation twice. I think I need some guide about how to write match query command like this.

**details is below:**

I have node types: **U, A, I**

node‘s relation is:

```
U -R_UA_REL-> A -R_HAS-> I
```

**U** has property of {user_id: xxx} 
**A** has propert of {create_time:xxx} 
**I** has properties of {id:xxx, value:xxx}

The search order is:

> 1. find U with property of user_id as u;
> 2. find A:a1 through u's relation of R_UA_REL, get a1;
> 3. filter a1 by it's R_HAS relation to I with I's id and value, get a2;
> 4. filter a2 by it's R_HAS relation to I with I's id and value, get a3;
> 5. return a3 as result;

My match query command is:

```
match 
    {class:U, as: u, where:(user_id = 60000021380)}
    .out('R_UA_REL') 
    {class:A, as: a1, where:(create_time > 1509033600 and create_time < 1509206400000)}
    .out('R_HAS')
    {class:I, as: i1,  where:(id = "5d6fc56bf2d34bd09d394b1ce3d357e1" and value = "交通费")}
    .in('R_HAS')
    {class:A, as: a2}
    .out('R_HAS')
    {class:I, as: i2,  where:(id = "c59994b93c22488fa6f3cd7563715923" and value > 1 and value < 130)}
    .in('R_HAS')
    {class:A, as: a3}
    return a3
limit 10000;
```

The data scale of different query step is:

```
(U:u)-R_UA_REL->(A:a1)-R_HAS->(I:i1)<-R_HAS-(A:a2)-R_HAS->(I:i2)<-R_HAS-(A:a3)
  1             ~1000K       ~10000K        ~290K         ~2900K         ~20K
```

The query is very very slow !!! it takes about 11s one time.

the orientdb version is: orientdb-community-2.2.28

**>>>> my question is: how can I do to optimize this query?**

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, how many data do you have? Because if you have a lot of data you can use the indexes.

Comment: I just load a part of data into orientdb, and the data size I given in my question. it's about 1000K of A, 1000*10K of I.

Comment: Have you tried using indexes?

Comment: Yes, every used properties has a NOTUNIQUE index!